# Rails navigation helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two rails helper on my application helper:

```
  def active_class(link_path)
    current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
  end

  def active_class_white(link_path)
    current_page?(link_path) ? 'active-white' : ''
  end
```

One is for regular links the other one is for the submenus. Usually I place the link like this:

```
 <%= link_to "Home", root_path(:anchor => 'home'), class: "nav-link #{active_class('/')}", :"data-id" => "home" %>
```

Now here's my problem. On my homepage I got this link where it will slide to a particular section of the site thus requires a character like `#about`. If I place:

```
<%= link_to "About", root_path(:anchor => 'about'), class: "nav-link #{active_class('/#about')}", :"data-id" => "about" %>
```

It's still putting the active class on the `home` text instead of the about (the homepage is a one page slider type).

Another thing is that for complicated url like the devise edit profile, I tried to put the ff:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(current_user), class: "dropdown-item #{active_class_white('/users/edit/:id')}" %>
```

Placing `/users/edit/:id` doesn't work on this kind of URL: `http://localhost:3000/users/edit.13`

On this two kinds of URL my code doesn't work. Any idea how to make them work or turn this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchors are purely client-side and are not sent along with the request to the server. So, the only way to implement the first part of your question is through Javascript. You can listen for a click event on links then add the active class to the one that was clicked.

The second part of your question, where you pass in the `:id` segment key, can be solved by passing a route helper (along with an object) to `current_page?` instead of an explicit string...

```
class: <%= active_class(edit_user_registration_path(current_user)) %>
```